# Incanter labelling a time-series-chart with multiple series

Tags: clojure, charts, incanter

I have an incanter time-series chart, which I can't seem to generate with the correct series labels on. My data looks like this:

```
__________________________
| :Time | :Count | :Name |
| 12344 |    0   | "A"   |
| 12344 |    1   | "B"   |
| 12344 |    2   | "C"   |
| 12345 |    4   | "A"   |
```

I have tried setting the series label to a small set of strings, but only the first value is displayed on the chart for the first series. My (incorrect sample) code to plot the chart looks like this:

```
      (view (time-series-plot :Time :Count
               :x-label "Date"
               :y-label "Points"
               :title "My Cool Graph"
               :legend true
               :group-by :Name
               :series-label "A" "B" "C"
               :data data-to-graph
               :points true
               ))
```

Any pointers much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Juse a guess but the line:

```
:series-label "A" "B" "C"
```

is getting converted into a map like:

```
{:series-label "A", "B" "C"}
```

which is still only passing a single item as :series-label.
perhaps you would like:

```
:series-label ["A" "B" "C"]
```

though I'm not sure if incanter takes multiple values for labels.

Comment: Have you tried this? I'm relatively certain I had tried this approach and it had looked like the result of (str ["A" "B" "C"]) being displayed as the label for the first series.

Comment: Just checked again, passing a coll has exactly the same effect as the non-coll.

Comment: I was primarily trying to point out the syntax error in the call to time-series-plot in the question which is causing :series-label to be passed one string "A" as it's value and the "B" "C" is treated as the next key -> value pair.

Comment: True, I can't seem to identify what I should be passing though :)